# Uncaught ReferenceError: my function is not defined

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to build a CakePHP application which will allow a user to update their address information, and then store the new lat/lon in the database.  I am using Google's geocoder to retrieve lat/lon information but my function isn't working.  I have almost no experience with Javascript so I am not sure what I have done wrong.  My code is kind of an amalgamation of what I have seen around the internet.  Please, if someone could advise me, that would be great.

Here is my geocode function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getLatLong(address){
  var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var address =<?php echo $this->data['Location']['address'].' '.$this->data['Location']['city'].', '.$this->data['Location']['state'].' '.$this->data['Location']['zip']; ?>;
  geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            return results[0].geometry.location;
            alert('The address is' + address);
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }

   });

  }
</script>
```

Above my html, here is the script to call it onLoad of the page:

```
<script>
if(window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent('onload', getLatLong());
} else {
if(window.onload) {
    var curronload = window.onload;
    var newonload = function() {
        curronload();
        getLatLong();
    };
    window.onload = newonload;
} else {
    window.onload = getLatLong();
}
}
</script>
```

I have in the head of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

When I load the page and inspect it with chrome, I see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getLatLong is not defined   (anonymous function)1:89
1:106      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may run across this, I got it working by changing my javascript function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var geocoder;
function getLatLong(address){

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var add = document.getElementById("LocationAddress");

  var address =add.value;
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address':address},function(results, status){
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML="<strong>"+results[0].geometry.location.lat()+"</strong><br />";
            document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML="<strong>"+results[0].geometry.location.lng()+"</strong>";

          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }

   });
```

}

where before I had been using

```
return results[0].geometry.location;
        alert('The address is' + address);
```

which didn't work, as soon as I replaced it with document.write(results[0]geometry.location); my alert started working.  I also made sure to define a var called geocoder before my function.

Comment: Well, if you `return` from a function, the function terminates. Following statements are not executed. That's the same in other languages as well. You could have switched the lines and it would work as well, although you don't need a return statement anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I had 'return' in there until I figured out how I was going to actually use the data that I got.  I am a programming noob, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the resulting code. I bet it is

```
var address = address here;
```

You have to put the PHP output in quotes to make it a valid JavaScript string:

```
var address = "<?php echo ... ?>";
```

Comment: That sounded good, and I tried it, but it didn't work...the Unexpected identifier error went away, but 'getLatLong' was still not defined.

Comment: Make sure that the function is defined before you use it, i.e. attach it as event handler. Second, instead of calling the function and pass its return value as event handler, you have to pass/assign a reference instead. I.e. it should be `window.attachEvent('onload', getLatLong);` and  `window.onload = getLatLong;`.

Comment: I got it working.  See my answer below.  Thank you for your help!